# Why is pi transcendental?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers

I thought I understood the definition of transcendental numbers, but recently I was thinking about infinite series and a question was raised that I couldn't answer.

If we write a finite number of terms for the Taylor series expansion of $\sin(x)$ centered around $0$, then assuming that a finite number of terms could approximate sine past $\pi$, wouldn't this make one of the roots to the polynomial $\pi$?

I may just be misunderstanding something about transcendental numbers or forgetting an important part of the rules of series, but if this is the case, could someone point out my mistake?

Comment: Try looking at such polynomials, they are close to sin - but never equal except at zero.

Comment: Any real number has approximations by a sequence of rational values, so that every real number is as close as we wish to a rational number.  However this doesn't help show that all real numbers are rational or (per your Question) that $\pi$ is algebraic (satisfies a polynomial).  So the "finite number of terms for the Taylor series" of $\sin(x)$ would be a polynomial, but $\pi$ would not be a root of that polynomial.  The topic of transcendence of $\pi$ has been discussed previously, but I'm not clear whether a proof of its transcendence is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've seen proofs of its transcendence, I just seemed to forget that unless it is an infinite series, the polynomial will never actually equal the function which clears up my misunderstanding. Despite this, I do have another related question. Can you factor the infinite series into an infinite product of binomials?

Comment: Try looking at Weierstrass Factorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truncated Taylor polynomial for $\sin(x)$ still never actually equals $\sin(x)$ except at zero. So the polynomials will have roots as close to $\pi$ as you want, but never equal.